# Is it possible to export my Google Listen Status?

Tags: settings, cyanogenmod

I am playing with the idea of switching from a rooted stock Froyo ROM on my Droid to a Cyanogen ROM, and one of the things that is holding me back is the Google Listen status.

I want to be able to preserve the contents of my queue, and, if possible, the last stopped point on any episodes in the queue.  It would also be great if I didn't have to re-download all of the episodes in my queue (I prefer to download them in advance, when I am on wifi, rather than stream them).  If I have to re-download, that isn't a big deal, but it would be nice if I could skip this.

Is this possible?  This seems to be the only thing that does not live in the cloud (at least that affects me).

Comment: How about exporting to a different podcatcher?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using a utility such as [TitaniumBackup](http://matrixrewriter.com/android/) to completely back-up all your applications **and** your data. It will be stored on your SD card so that you can restore them all after you've installed your new ROM, and you wouldn't even notice that it was gone.

Comment: +1 Titanium is the way to go if you are rooted and switching from stock to custom rom (or to another custom rom)

Comment: This looks like exactly what I have been looking for. Titanium backup, where have you been all my life?

Comment: This is actually one of the few apps I've paid for the donate version. It's really nice to be able to just set it to back-up right before I switch to a new ROM.

Comment: Titanium Backup is a great app. I will upvote this answer. Too bad it doesn't do what I really want, which is to transfer the queue to another podcast program (like BeyondPod) now that Google Listen is probably never going to be updated again.